# Not able to use images if I call gb4e.sty

Tags: graphics, incompatibility, linguistics, gb4e

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{gb4e,qtree,skull}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../74934_Art/Hackl.jpg}
\caption{Results of Hackl et~al. (2012)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I comment the package "`gb4e.sty`" then its works fine. If I call that package then the below error occurs:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
^#1->
     \gb@ifnextchar _{\automath@two ^{#1}}{\ensuremath {\sp {#1}}}
l.28  \catcode`\noexpand\^^A
                            \the\catcode`\^^A\relax
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

But based on my requirement, I need to use both packages, Please suggest...

Comment: I removed the tag `clash` because it did not add any useful information (as I did with other tags in some of your older posts). Please refrain from creating new tags that are either not applicable to many questions or simply do not add any meaningful detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gb4e` package makes the underscore and the caret "active" characters so that they can be used outside of math mode. This is useful in many situations, but can interfere with other things quite easily if you're not aware of it.

The simplest solution is to turn the feature of immediately after loading the package:

```
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
```

If you find the feature useful, then it's helpful to load the package late in the loading order, or turn it on selectively.  If you activate it, you things like underscores in filenames will cause problems, as in your example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{qtree,skull}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../74934_Art/Hackl.jpg}
\caption{Results of Hackl et~al. (2012)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right...

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the cases where you need to change the order of package loading.

*Update:* As [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) noted, gb4e makes the underscore active and paths with underscores (which I did not use in my test) break this setup. So this will only avoid the load-time error (which may be enough if you do not intend to use underscores in paths), but his answer also solves the OP's issue.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e,qtree,skull}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Results of Hackl et~al. (2012)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem completely: package loading helps, but there will still be a problem with  the underscore in the graphics path, since `gb4e` makes `_` active.

Comment: @AlanMunn You are completely right, unfortunately, I do ignore picture paths in answers and did not notice it. I'll add this note to my post, thanks.